# Multiple could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer Postgresql and Resque

Tags: postgresql, resque, puma

I have a server that runs Postgresql. in the logs I am seeing this message for my resque based 'worker' box, multiple times a minute. Some minutes there isn't a message, others could be 10 times.

```
2016-01-12 13:40:36 EST:1.1.8.2(33899):[16141]: LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

Now when i go into the `1.1.8.2` box to look at `netstat -ntp` i don't see a port 33899, and most of them are at least in the 40xxx range by now. That may be conjecture but I'm at a loss to find out why a Redis/Resque/Puma Rails stack would be printing out these messages, let alone what that means even if i get to the bottom of it.

Will I gain memory back if they are closed 'normally'?

Is this a thing to be wary of?

How does one debug OLD ports that are open when the db box and the worker box both don't display the ports any more?

Comment: Is it always from port 33899? To me, it looks like a kind of monitoring test, e.g. if the server is still alive. A monitoring software which just opens the port and closes it without reading from it would cause such a message.

Comment: Thanks, but it sometimes is incremental, so if there were five in a row it's pretty much 33899 33890, 33892...etc not always linear though. i am guessing that autovaccum is running , maybe, and closing old ass ports from 1/2 an hour ago. for instance. but have no idea if that'd be true or where to start on that theory.

Comment: So you can rule out a monitoring software checking the port? autovacuum does not care about connections. Maybe a tcpdump of database connections from the mentioned host 1.1.8.2 can shed light on this problem?

Comment: i'm looking into the tcpdump too, man that spits out a lot of stuff. first time using that. No monitoring software, but New Relic. but could that be doing `stuff` i wonder...

Answer (score 6):

This message is probably due to the resque worker task not closing the database connection before it exits. It's not a huge problem, but presumably Postgres is doing a little extra work to clean it up, and it makes a mess of your log file...

One solution is to add a hook to your resque worker's task file (the same file that contains the `self.perform` definition):

```
  def self.after_perform(*args)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end
```